# What does "Saving: time" stand for in the the finished command line render?

Tags: command-line

Using blender from the command line e.g. `blender -b` I see `Time: 02:11.63 (Saving: 00:00.52)`at the finished output.

What for is this part: `(Saving: 00:00.52)`?

Answer (score 3):

I assume it is the time to write the render result to disk, but --cycles-print-stats should give you a more detailed readout.

Comment: That would make perfect sense, and thus is not so.  It's not at all related to the disk i/o time.

Answer (score 2):

The value is printed by the function `do_write_image_or_movie` that you can find in [pipeline.c](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/render/intern/source/pipeline.c#L2307)

There are no comments indicating what it should be, but it is the time it takes to print the "Time:..." part of the message plus the time it takes to execute any callbacks.

(I think that's a bug, but that's what it's actually printing.)